# Move cell values from one cell to another with scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Move cell values from one sheet to another using a button.

Consider 3 sheets.

One sheet is called "Tentative Attendees."
It contains a column of names. Say cell A1 contains "John Doe," then cell A2 contains "James Does," and so on with all cells in the A column.

The second page is called "Present Attendees" -- for the attendees who have checked in. It is currently blank.

The third page contains a dropdown list of all the names in column A of the "Tentative Attendees" sheet. Say, for example, John Doe checks in. So his name would then be selected in the dropdown.

Under the dropdown is a button, that says "Present."

If the cell is filled with John Doe's name and the button is pressed, then John Doe's name gets transferred from cell A1 in "Tentative Attendees" to cell A1 in "Present Attendees."

Could someone give me the code to execute such a command? I do not know the function that would allow me to transfer the value of cell X to cell Y assuming that cell Z = cell X and the button is pressed. Any help?

Comment: Welcome. Would you please add a brief description of your search/research efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a dynamic data validation list of "Tentative Attendees". As each name on the list is selected as being Present, you want that name to be removed from the list. You proposed a three sheet solution, though you did not offer any formula or script to deliver the outcome.

The following solution is an implementation of the question: [Sheets - remove item from data validation once it is used](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/11449172?hl=en) on Google Docs Editors Help (Community).

In this solution, your third (un-named) sheet is not required. The solution is achieved with the two sheets "Tentative Attendees" and "Present Attendees".

Onn "Tentative Attendees" enter this formula in a cell adjacent to the full list of "Tentative Attendees":

`=ArrayFormula(if(countif('Present Attendees'!A2:A,A2:A)=0,A2:A,))`

This cell and the list that it creates are used as the Data validation source for the Attendee names on "Present Attendees". As names are added to the Attendee List, those same names are dropped from the validation list. The effect is that only the names of Tentative Attendees who have not yet registered will appear on the Validation list.

---

**Present Attendees - Validation List definition**

[image: Present Attendees - Validation List definition]

---

**Tentative Attendees - Screenshot**

### [image: Tentative Attendees - Screenshot]